# Which Is invariant to rotation, SiftFeatureDetector or SiftDescriptorExtractor?

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

I am using OpenCV for image recognition and I want to know whether the rotation invariance of `cv::SIFT` is achieved due to it's detector `cv::SiftFeatureDetector` or due to it's descriptor `cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor`. Same thing for SURF.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with respect to SIFT. Going through point 1 and 4 [THIS PAGE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html#sift-intro) clears things up.

**1. Detection:** SIFT uses DOG (Difference of Gaussians) to detect blobs in an image. These are the so-called *keypoints* of an image

**2. Description:** Every detected keypoint is given a descriptor. This is calculated using pixels from the neighborhood. It is in the descriptor where robustness to scale, rotation illumination and others is embedded.

Here is an excerpt from the doc mentioned:

> It is represented as a vector to form keypoint descriptor. In addition to this, several measures are taken to achieve robustness against illumination changes, rotation etc.

I presume the same for SURF as well.

Comment: But when I try to combine `cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor` whith another `cv::FeatureDetector` (which is different from `cv::SiftFeatureDetector`) I cannot achieve rotation invariant, why?